# make divs overlap with Grid Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

The goal is that when div increases, it will overlap  the next row(s) and will not push them down.
I tried using `position: absolute;` but it destroyed the form of the Grid Layout.
It's important to me to keep the shape of the grid, it's essential.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you specify the height on hover. You could also specify a negative bottom margin to compensate (and use z-index to make sure it appears on top).

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```